# Angular 2: Reload current page on browser back / forward / refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Been doing some research, is there any way to just reload the current page on user clicking the browser back button or forward? For SPA.

I know it is not recommended to restrict users from using their browser buttons and probably not much control of them either.

I was looking into something like this:

```
      @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
      onPopState(event) {
        console.log("Back Button detected!");
        window.history.forward();

  }
```

Update: This is closer to what I want to achieve, but if the user spams the back button, he can potentially get back to a previous screen in SPA. (I am not using { skipLocationChange: true } so that may resolve that issue.

```
      <script>
        history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
        window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        history.go(1);
      };

  </script>
```

Comment: can you not control what goes in the history? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028397/angular-2-prevent-router-from-adding-to-history